# Как сделать, чтобы рабочая часть JFrame была равна устанавливаемым размерам окна?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Есть код:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(200,200);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

При его запуске создаётся окно с размером `186х193`.
Но мне нужна рабочая часть окна `200х200`
(без учёта рамки и заголовка).

Мне приходиться делать вычисления, чтобы рабочая часть окна имела размер `200х200`:

```
frame.setSize(216,239);
```

можно как-то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Я исправил ответ, посмотрите его пожалуйста. Если что-то у вас не получается, нажмите "править" под вопросом и добавьте текст или картинку с вашими проблемами в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

#### **Из-за чего происходит проблема?**

`JFrame` - это окно вашего приложения. Но у каждого окна есть рамка:

[image: рамка]

То есть:

```
JFrame = рабочая часть + рамка
```

И рамка учитывается в размерах окна, когда вы просто вызываете метод `setSize()`.

#### **Как решить проблему?**

Есть два варианта:

**Вариант 1**: Установить напрямую
размер рабочей поверхности окна (`ContentPane`).
Этот вариант взят с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593322/why-does-the-jframe-setsize-method-not-set-the-size-correctly):

```java
jfr.getContentPane().setSize(800,400);
```

Этот вариант решает проблему, устанавливая размер **именно рабочей части окна** (`ContentPane`).

**Вариант 2**: установить панель (`JPanel`) как `ContentPane`. Это можно сделать вот так:

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

На enSO тоже самое предлагают сделать немного по-другому:

```java
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,800));
jf.getContentPane().add(jp);
jf.pack();
```

**Важно**: добавить на фрейм панель нужно до того, как вы отображаете окно:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.setSize(200,200);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

#### Как работает вариант 2?

Раз в комментариях спрашивали, объясню подробней.

Когда вы вызываете метод `setContentPane()` и передаёте в параметры `JPanel` вы устанавливаете панель как рабочую часть окна, а не просто добавляете её на фрейм. Вы говорите: *"панель - это рабочая часть окна, все остальные панели нужно добавлять на неё, ну и раз есть у окна обозначенная рабочая часть, то и при установки размеров фрейма размер устанавливать нужно этой рабочей части"*. **Если бы вы просто добавили `JPanel` методом `add()`, то ничего бы не поменялось.**

#### **Ссылки**

[Пост на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593322/why-does-the-jframe-setsize-method-not-set-the-size-correctly).

[И здесь немного про ContentPane](https://java-online.ru/libs-swing.xhtml#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20ContentPane%20%2D%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F,%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E).

Comment: Я не спец по джаве, но такое ощущение, что в ответе кода установки размеров не хватает.

Comment: @Qwertiy код установки размеров фрейма у автора правильный, и он бы работал бы корректно, если бы на фрейм добавляли панель. Но ятобы у вас не возникало "странных ощущений", добавлю его в ответ =).

Comment: Т. е. JFrame по-разному обрабатывает устанавливаемый размер в зависимости от того, добавлена ли на него JPanel? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy когда у меня была такая же проблема, это мне лично помогло. На самом деле это вроде как даже логично: фрейм - это окно, и `setSize()` устанавливает размеры **всего** окна. А если у окна есть контент, то ставиться размеры для его контента.

Comment: @Qwertiy только что нашёл на английском аналоге есть похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593322/why-does-the-jframe-setsize-method-not-set-the-size-correctly

Comment: JPanel не прокатывает. ничего не изменилось. попробовал и с англ.сайта вариант тоже не проходит

Comment: @damp.ali пожалуйста, добавьте код вашей попытки в вопрос и я посмотрю, почему ваш вариант не сработал.

Comment: новый вопрос? или что сделать не понял

Comment: @damp.ali Пожалуйста, нажмите "править" под вопросом, и добавьте информацию о том, что вы сделали.

Comment: пишет красным цветом что-то с кодом не так оформлен что ли.

Comment: @damp.ali у среда разработки об ошибках пишет?

Comment: @Qwertiy внёс правку, вроде теперь стало немного ясней.

Comment: @Зонтик, круто! отличный ответ получился!