# Что за магические цифры мы указываем при создании jframe java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

После создания `JFrame` можно ему задать размеры через методы `setSize()` и `setBounds()`, но если указать просто нужный нам размер, например 400×400, то окно будет меньше, чтобы оно было нужного нам размера, к ширине нужно прибавить 16, а к высоте 38, что это за цифры такие и почему их нужно прибавлять, если высоту ещё можно спихнуть на панель навигации, где кнопка свернуть закрыть и полный экран, хотя это с натяжкой, ведь я не думаю, что navigation bar занимает 38 пикселей, то с шириной это не объяснимо
Так же при попытке отписываться какие либо объекты, к их координатам нужно прибавлять: к абсциссе 8, а к ординате 32, вопрос: откуда эти цифры?
А при получении координаты клика мыши через `MouseListener`, от этой координаты нужно отнять 8 и 32, чтобы получить правильные координаты клика относительно самого окна
Так откуда эти цифры, почему они такие?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499751/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-jframe-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы рабочая часть JFrame была равна устанавливаемым размерам окна?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499751/)